# Est-ce que cet exercice de grammaire a d'autres réponses possibles que celles suggérées?

Tags: grammaire, pluriel, déterminants

J’ai une question concernant un exercice de mon livre de grammaire:

> Transformez les phrases en utilisant *tout, toute, tous,
>   toutes*:
>
> 1. Chaque seconde compte lorsqu’on court le marathon.
> 2. Chaque dimanche, Lili court 10 kilomètres à pied.
> 3. Il cherche a réussir sa carrière par n’importe quel moyen.
> 4. Méline était tellement fatiguée qu’elle a dormi la totalité du week-end.
> 5. Nous avons investi la totalité de nos économies pour faire ce voyage.

Les réponses suggérées sont:

> 1. Toutes les secondes comptent lorsqu’on court le marathon.
> 2. Tous les dimanches, Lili court 10 kilomètres à pied.
> 3. Il cherche à réussir sa carrière par tous les moyens.
> 4. Méline était tellement fatiguée qu’elle a dormi tout le week-end.
> 5. Nous avons investi toutes nos économies pour faire ce voyage.

Ma question: est-ce qu’il y a d’autres possibilités? Je pense que:

> 1. Oui: toute seconde compte …
> 2. Peut-être, mais je doute: tout dimanche, …
> 3. Oui: … par tout moyen.
> 4. Non, dire par example “tous les week-ends” n’a pas le même sens.
> 5. Non, “toute notre économie” n’aurait pas le même sens.

Comment: Seule l'alternative du 1 est valide « Toute seconde compte » les autres sont incorrectes

Comment: Ok merci! J'aimerais savoir alors pourquoi les deux autres alternatives (pour les phrases 2 et 3) sont incorrectes, est-ce qu'il s'agit d'erreurs grammaticaux ou est-ce qu'ils changent le sens des phrases originaux?

Comment: « tout dimanche » peut signifier toute le journée du dimanche; pour la phrase 3, il est effectivement possible d'utiliser un singulier mais je préfère le pluriel dans ce contexte, en général on utilise **des** moyens pour réussir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 - "toute seconde compte" est correct du point de vue de la grammaire, mais inusité, personne ne le dirait comme ça. Le plus courant serait "chaque seconde compte".

2 - "tous les dimanches" signifie "every sunday" donc tu n'as pas le choix. "tout dimanche" serait une erreur. "Tous" est plus proche de "every" en anglais, alors que "tout" veut plutôt dire "all of", donc "elle a couru tout dimanche" est une phrase incorrecte dont le sens le plus proche serait: "elle a passé la journée entière à courir" ou "elle a couru toute la journée". Ces deux sont d'ailleurs proches de l'anglais (she spent all day running, she ran all day).

3- "par tout moyen." même chose que pour le 1, ce n'est pas une erreur, d'ailleurs on rencontre cette façon de le dire en mathématiques par exemple, mais ce n'est pas l'usage courant.

4- "Non, dire par example “tous les week-ends” n’a pas le même sens."

C'est vrai, voir la différence entre "tous" et "tout".

5- Non, “toute notre économie” n’aurait pas le même sens.

C'est vrai, mais tu pourrais dire "tout l'argent qu'on avait économisé". En français "économies" au pluriel est l'argent mis de côté (EN: savings) mais "économie" au singulier c'est en anglais "the economy". Le verbe "économiser" correspond à "to save".

Comment: *Toute seconde compte* est rare, mais pas inusité.